# (String Permutation) from interviewstreet.com

Tags: string, permutation

****Question (String Permutation)*** from interviewstreet.com*

- Given two strings, write a method to decide if one is a permutation
  of
      the other. Your solution should consider case sensitivity and
      whitespace as significant.
- A permutation of a set of objects is an arrangement of those objects
  into a particular order. For example, there are six permutations of
  the string "abc", namely "abc", "acb", "bac", "bca", "cab", and
  "cba".
- Output:
     Return 1 if the two strings are permutations of each other.
     Return 0 if the two strings are not permutations of each other.
- abc  acb     cab     cba     bac     bca

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

private  Set permutations;

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
 //   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String string1 = sc.nextLine();
    //String string2 = sc.nextLine();

String string1 = "str";
    String string2 = "str";

    Solution solution = new Solution();
    int output = solution.permutation(string1, string2);
    System.out.println(output);
}

public  void stringPermuation(String s1, String s2) {

if (s2.length() > 0) {

for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(s1 + s2.charAt(i)+","+ s2.substring(0, i)+" +"+ s2.substring(i + 1));

    stringPermuation(s1 + s2.charAt(i),
        s2.substring(0, i) + s2.substring(i + 1));
    }}
else{
    permutations.add(s1);
    System.out.println(s1);
}
}

public Set stringPermuation(String s) {
permutations = new HashSet<String>();
stringPermuation("", s);
return permutations;
}



private  int permutation(String string1, String string2) {
int result = 0;
 Set<String> setString1 = stringPermuation(string1);
 Set<String> setString2 = stringPermuation(string2);
    // create an iterator

     System.out.println("There are total of " + setString1.size() + " permutations in String1:");
     System.out.println("There are total of " + setString2.size() + " permutations in String2:");

     if(setString1.size() == setString2.size())
        result=IterateSet(setString1,setString2);

    //Return 1 if string1 is a permutation of string2
    //Return 0 if string1 is not a permutation of string2
return result;
}

public  int IterateSet(Set setString1,Set setString2){
    int  i=  0;
    Iterator<String> it = setString1.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if(setString2.contains(it.next()) && i == 0)
         i=1;
    }
return i;}}
```

Comment: Is these a question hiding here?

Answer (score 2):

...Sort the characters of the two strings (lexicographically) and if the two sorted strings are equal, the originals are permutations of each other.